# Chrome's URL field prohibits some URLs from being drag-drop'ed into Finder for auto .webloc file generation. Why is this?

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome

[Here is a six-second video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Gz0AfnKnO8sQXZftF2arO5hiR5vTvSq/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the scenario I can't seem to figure out. Why won't the second URL become a .webloc like the first one?  ..and is there a useful workaround if not a solution to this problem?

Chrome and OSX (Catalina) are both current.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you link the latter URL, so that one can try?

Comment: Sorry.  Here you go.  Thanks in advance! https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/evans/N27531.0001.001/1:11?rgn=div1;view=fulltext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some trial and error, I could find out a working method, but not the problem.

- Click the address bar once. Even if the site is https, it won't show on the protocol on the first click and the rest of the URL will get selected.
- Drag and drop the selected part of the URL.
- If you click again and the site shows `https://` etc., drag and drop of that URL wouldn't work.

Comment: Cursor position is irrelevant, except when mouse button is depressed atop the padlock icon, as seen in my stupid video.  I've used this feature for years and years, but every so often, and for a reason I cannot for the life of me figure out, Chrome and/or OSX prevent the operation from working.  I can't identify a single commonality among all the cases I remember it NOT working as it should.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you try after removing focus from URL and putting it in say the webpage in the `.edu` site case?

Comment: Tried that.  No success.  Here is the URL for those who wish to help troubleshoot: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/evans/N27531.0001.001/1:11?rgn=div1;view=fulltext

Comment: Thanks so much for all the testing.  Unfortunately I was unsuccessful using your method, but WAS successful finally identifying a workaround.  As you noted, clicking within the address bar a second time will reveal the "https://."  What I did was simply delete the "s" and try again.  Amazingly, it worked -- the address dropped in as a .webloc.  Not sure this is the ideal solution, but at least it worked in this one instance.

Comment: Sorry for delay, and thanks again ankii for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. It turned out the url was just too long. I had typed a long note into chrome and wanted to drag it to the desktop as a reminder. When I reduced the size of the google search, it let me drag and drop the link like usual. I'm assuming it was larger than the max file name in finder, but I didn't bother to confirm that. Not great that there is zero feedback and it just fails.